# access response object when using socket.io in nodejs/express app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Normally, I can change the view of my client from the server using a GET/POST method in my server like this:

```
app.get('/hello', function(req, res){
    res.render('helloView', {})
});
```

Where `helloView` is some html/jade view file.

But I need to be able to call `res.render('helloView', {})` when I receive a `socket.io` message from my client.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('showHellow', function(client_data){
        res.render('helloView', {}) // <---- obviously this fails, so how
        //can I call res.render('helloView') from here???
    });
});
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: That is not possible. You have a big misunderstanding of what web sockets can do. You won't have `res` in that context because there is nothing to respond to. You could compile your `helloView` template and send that over the socket, but it would still require you to handle that message on the client-side by updating the DOM yourself with the HTML sent in the message. You'd be better off just having your client redirect the browser to /hello to perform the normal HTTP GET request.

Comment: Thanks @idbehold, I simply went ahead and sent a server->client confirmation using socket.io and then sent a client->server GET message which in turn changes the view. Seems a little round-about though.